# INSERT INTO … ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE …. with condition?

Tags: mysql, date, sql-update, sql-insert, on-duplicate-key

I am still wondering if there is something like a conditional on duplicate update in MySQL 5.7

I have a table which is updated by different sources.

Let’s assume I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE t 
(
    name VARCHAR(100),
    value INT,
    last update DATETIME
)
```

I have 3 rows

| name | value | lastupdate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 10 | 2021-01-01 |
| b | 20 | 2021-02-01 |
| c | 30 | 2021-03-01 |

Now I have some data to be imported

| name | value | lastupdate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 20 | 2021-01-01 |
| b | 40 | 2021-01-01 |
| c | 60 | 2021-04-01 |

The result of the query should be

| name | value | lastupdate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 20 | 2021-01-01 |
| b | 20 | 2021-02-01 |
| c | 60 | 2021-03-01 |

Can this be done by one insert query or must I check first if the last update of the existing data in the table is newer then the date of the import data?

Comment: In your sample result, is the "lastupdate" "2021-04-01" or not (e.g. shall it be updated too, or only "value"?) Also, on duplicate key requires, well, a key. Can you specify your primary key? (It has to be "name" to work as you want it to, so can you confirm that that's your primary key?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that `name` is the `PRIMARY KEY` of the table or is defined as `UNIQUE`, you can use a `CASE` expression:

```
INSERT INTO t (name, value, lastupdate) VALUES
  ('a', 20, '2021-01-01'),
  ('b', 40, '2021-01-01'),
  ('c', 60, '2021-04-01')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
value = CASE WHEN VALUES(lastupdate) >= lastupdate THEN VALUES(value) ELSE value END;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=63e3981a7841504874a423466a59b40b).

Note that (from [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)):

> The use of VALUES() to refer to the new row and columns is deprecated
> beginning with MySQL 8.0.20, and is subject to removal in a future
> version of MySQL. Instead, use row and column aliases, as described in
> the next few paragraphs of this section.

So, if your version of MySql is 8.0.20+ it is recommended to use an alias instead of `VALUES()`:

```
INSERT INTO t (name, value, lastupdate) VALUES
  ('a', 20, '2021-01-01'),
  ('b', 40, '2021-01-01'),
  ('c', 60, '2021-04-01') AS new
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
t.value = CASE WHEN new.lastupdate >= t.lastupdate THEN new.value ELSE t.value END;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e0147b11ab47ee096077d09613b0ded4).

Comment: Thx for the suggestion